# Is it possible have a Light Node with Hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I did not find in official literature if is it possible to have a Light node/peer with Hyperledger technology?

I am using Hyperledger fabric and composer and I wish to have peers without the full copy of the blockchain/ledger.

I would like to have these light nodes only to have access to the network and maybe help processing transactions but not to store it.

I have this concern because some members of my private blockchain network will not have storage capacity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a light node. In Fabric it is called a client.

From the v1.2 docs: [Architecture Explained](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/arch-deep-dive.html):

> There are three types of nodes:
>
> 1. Client or submitting-client: a client that submits an actual transaction-invocation to the endorsers, and broadcasts transaction-proposals to the ordering service.
> 2. Peer: a node that commits transactions and maintains the state and a copy of the ledger (see Sec, 1.2). Besides, peers can have a special endorser role.
> 3. Ordering-service-node or orderer: a node running the communication service that implements a delivery guarantee, such as atomic or total order broadcast.